Does the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights package include a dependency to the Azure.Core package?
I just noticed there are some mentions about Azure.Core.TokenCredential and Azure.Core.Identity in the TelemetryConfiguration class from Microsoft.ApplicationInsights package (version 2.21.0) but I don't find any Azure.Core package or references to it in my projects.
The Nuget package documentation doesn't mention a dependency on Azure.Core: nuget.org
Does Microsoft.ApplicationInsights includes any dependency on Azure.Core?

Check the below sol.


When you Install the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights package directly from the NuGet Package, only System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource  is seen.



but I don't find any Azure.Core package or references to it in my projects.


If you configure Application Insights from Connected Services,


Both Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore and Azure.Identity packages will be Installed.


You can see Azure.Core package under Azure.Identity.



Azure.Core is dependent on Azure.Identity, which can be used if you want to work with Credentials for Azure SDK

